Bindingするbool型プロパティを繰り返し文でN個作って、N個のToggleButtonのIsCheckedプロパティとBindするには？
コードビハインドでToggleButtonのIsCheckedプロパティにViewModelのプロパティをバインドするときは以下のような感じでプロパティの名前を指定するので、ViewModelで静的にプロパティを作って名前を指定することは可能ですが、ViewModelでN個のプロパティを繰り返し文で作ると名前が同じなってしまうのでIsCheckedプロパティにバインドすることは不可能という認識ですが正しいですか？
Binding binding = new Binding(); binding.Path = new
PropertyPath("プロパティの名前");


何を作っているか(WPF?)と開発環境ぐらいは書いてはいかが？

試しにWindows11のCopilot(プレビュー版)でwpf mvvm dynamically generate multiple togglebutton and ischeked bool variable pairといったキーワードで質問を入力して問い合わせたら、何かそれっぽい回答があったので参考になるかも。

ChatGPTの回答で対処できました。
アドバイスいただきありがとうございます。
xaml
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ToggleButtonProperties}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Content="Toggle Button"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              Margin="1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

xaml.cs
public partial class ServerSim : UserControl
{
    ServerSimViewModel vm;
    public ServerSim(ServerSimViewModel _serverSimViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = _serverSimViewModel;
    }
}

viewmodel
public class ServerSimViewModel : BindableBase, IDisposable
{
    private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    private List<ReactiveProperty<bool>> _toggleButtonProperties;

    public List<ReactiveProperty<bool>> ToggleButtonProperties { get ; set ;}

    public ServerSimViewModel()
    {
        ToggleButtonProperties = new List<ReactiveProperty<bool>>();

        // Initialize ReactiveProperties for each button
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            ToggleButtonProperties.Add(new ReactiveProperty<bool>());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposables?.Dispose();           
    }
}

